# Traits Enum values

Tags: python, enthought

I'm having trouble setting an Enum value to one of it's possibility in a class...

If I have in an iPython window:

```
eTest = Enum('zero', 'one', 'two', 'three')
```

I can do:

```
eTest.value = eTest.values[2]
```

and `print eTest.value` gives me the correct answer: two

I'm trying the same thing in a python class, and it tells me that:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'values'
```

how can I set eTest to have the [3] value of the Enums without having to type in the word 'three'?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You do not work with `Enum` objects like this. The `Enum` object is just a kind of declaration that tells the `HasTraits` class that has one of these to make an instance attribute that does a particular kind of validation. This instance attribute will *not* be an `Enum` object: it will be one of the enumerated values. The `.value` attribute that you were modifying on the `Enum` object just changes what the *default value* is going to be. It's not something you set during the lifetime of your object.

```
from traits.api import Enum, HasTraits, TraitError


ETEST_VALUES = ['zero', 'one', 'two', 'three']


class Foo(HasTraits):
    eTest = Enum(*ETEST_VALUES)


f = Foo()
assert f.eTest == 'zero'
f.eTest = 'one'
f.eTest = ETEST_VALUES[3]

try:
    f.eTest = 'four'
except TraitError:
    print 'Oops! Bad value!'
```

> how can I set eTest to have the [3] value of the Enums without having to type in the word 'three'?

You can follow my example above and keep the list separate from the `Enum()` call and just index into it when you need to.

Comment: Excellent :)  One of these days I'll get the hang of Python and Traits :).  Your method works perfectly for me.